# $H_n(A,A)$ Relative Homology of the pair the space and itself

Tags: algebraic-topology, solution-verification

I am tasked with calculating the relative homology group $H_n(A, A)$ for a topological space A, without invoking that $(A, A)$ is trivially a good pair, thus $H_n(A, A) = \tilde{H_n}(A/A) = 0$, but my solution feels way too simple (as in there is almost nothing to do?):

Noting that on chain-level $$C_n(A,A):=C_n(A)/C_n(A)= 0,$$ thus all the boundary maps $\partial_n$ are zero-maps and we get $$H_n(A, A) = \ker(\partial)/\text{Im}(\partial) = 0 $$

I'm pretty convinced by this argument (there is no contradiction to what I'm expecting from intuition or the answer concluded from the "prohibited method"), the only reason I'm doubting is because my friends are saying they proved it by expanding to the long exact sequence of the pair and went from there and insist that this is the way and I cannot for my life go with that approach without falling back to this argument, but by then there is no point in expanding to the les. Any thoughts? Is there some slick way to see some cancellations on the les level that I'm missing?

Edit: This is on singular homology. Disclaimer that this is homework!

Comment: When something is obvious, don't ask for help from your friends to make it not obvious!

Comment: If homology is defined axiomatically for you, then you don't have access to anything called C, but you do have acess to the LES of a pair axiom. Moreover, are you certain that this fact that you are proving is not itself used in the argument that it suffices to consider singular homology?

Comment: @ZKe I didn't know that there are different homology theories based on some axiomatic definition since we were just introduced to simplicial and singular homology. That said, I've added that this excercise is on singular homology!

Comment: @ZKe Also am I understanding correctly that if I have a different homology theory, I have to prove this on the les level? But then that means there is a way to prove it without going to the chain level? (regardless of whether I'm working in singular homology or not, if I can assume that singular homology also fulfills the axioms?)

Comment: Sure, the LES of a pair is a requirement for a homology theory, and $H_n(A)\to H_n(A)$ is an isomorphism in that sequence for all n. This is sufficient information. That said if you are explicitly working in singular homology then your argument is fine.

Comment: And then you conclude from the isomorphism + exactness that the groups before and after are 0, correct?